# How to sort by two criteria on the same dimension

Tags: mdx

How would I do the following in mdx?

```
ORDER(
    -- order our team members
    {[Team].[Hierarchy].[Code].members, [Team].[Hierarchy].[All]},

   -- first by the number of losses (desc) in 2016
    ([Measures].[Losses], [Season].[Season].&[2016]), desc, -- sort by who had the most losses in 2015

   -- tiebreak on the name (asc)
   [Team].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Member_Name, asc
)
```

What would be the correct syntax for this? What I have right now is:

```
    ORDER(
        ORDER(
            {[Team].[Hierarchy].[Code].members, [Team].[Hierarchy].[All]},
            ([Measures].[Losses], [Season].[Season].&[2016]), -- sort by who had the most losses in 2015
            bdesc
        ),
        [Team].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Member_Name, 
        asc
    )
```

But that just ends up doing the outer sort and ignoring the inner sort.

Comment: Can you share some sample data showing what is returned at the moment and what do you want to be returned.

Comment: @MoazRub I think you should be able to use the AdventureWorks cube. Just find two people with the same sales amount (or anything that's the same) and as a secondary/tiebreaker sort, order by name desc.

Comment: Does the below help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Rank function for this. Here is a sample

```
with member 
[Measures].[Internet Order Count- Name] 
as 
[Measures].[Internet Order Count]+(1-([Measures].ProductNameRank/100))

member [Measures].ProductNameRank as
Rank([Product].[Product].currentmember, 
order(
extract(filter(([Date].[Calendar Year].currentmember,[Product].[Product].[Product]),[Measures].[Internet Order Count] >0),[Product].[Product])
,[Product].[Product].currentmember.name,desc)
)

select 
{[Measures].[Internet Order Count] --,[Measures].[Internet Order Count- Name],[Measures].ProductNameRank 
}
on 0,
order (
filter ([Product].[Product].[Product] ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count] >0)
,[Measures].[Internet Order Count- Name] 
,desc)
on 1 
from [Adventure Works]
where [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012]
```

Note, how the "All purpose Bike Stand" comes last

[image]